# How would I cancel this script based on the size of the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var $windows = $('.window');

            $windows.windows({
                snapping: true,
                snapSpeed: 200,
                snapInterval: 800,
                onScroll: function(s){},
                onSnapComplete: function($el){},
                onWindowEnter: function($el){}
            });
        });
```

Hi I need to know how to disable this script based off of the browser width. So I want the snapping to be false when the browser is less than 440px.

Sorry if I haven't worded this greatly and thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Replace `true` with a conditional that will evaluate to true or false when you want to

```
 $windows.windows({
            snapping: $(window).width() > 440 || $(window).height() > 440, //will be false when either dimension is less than 440, other wise it will be true
            snapSpeed: 200,
            snapInterval: 800,
            onScroll: function(s){},
            onSnapComplete: function($el){},
            onWindowEnter: function($el){}
        });
```

Comment: I just tried using this after your comment, and it seems that the code is still working even at a width below 440px? Sorry, bit of a noob at this...

Comment: Here's a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qGSk6/, Keep in mind my conditional returns false when BOTH width and height are less than 440. You may want to switch it to && instead of || if you want to check only one dimension

Comment: @user3083665: `$(window).width() > 440 || $(window).height() > 440` will only be executed *once* on page load. If you change the size after the that, the code won't be run again. `.windows` is not a default jQuery method. If you'd tell us which plugin you use, we might be able to give you a better solution.

Comment: @user3083665 This will work if you throw it inside a `$(window).resize(function() {})` like in the fiddle. @Felix Kling is right, it will only calculate once on page load. But sticking your call inside a window resize will have it call when that page resizes. It will also work if you call the function after resizing, since it will recalulate the width and height at the time of the function call.

Comment: @Esaevian how do I make that then, sorry I am quite new to this :/

Comment: @user3083665 See my fiddle from earlier,  jsfiddle.net/qGSk6. Just stick a function in `$(window).resize()` (http://api.jquery.com/resize/) and your function will be called every time the user resizes your window.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using responsive design? If so, you could just use an if statement based on the size of the container:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if($(".container").css("width") <= "440px") {
        ...add your code here
    }
});
```

If you are set on using the size of the window, I am sure you can apply this if statement using the window size.

Hope this helps!